How to add an element within text-content (PCDATA) of another element using python XML?
Consider this XML:
<p>Here is some text.</p>
Using the Python XML module, I would like to add an annotation with the following result:
<p>Here is <w>some</w> text.</p>
I.e., I would like to include a new element-node within the textual content.
Is there a convenient way to do that?
I can do a regex, replacing word with &lt;word&gt;, then transforming the XML to string, replace &lt; with < etc., and re-read the string as XML. It works in my case, but doesn't seem to be the right way.

What do you mean by "the Python XML module"? That is ambiguous. In the standard library, there are several modules in the xml package. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html.

With xml.etree.ElementTree you can append an element.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<p>Here is some text.</p>"""
p = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

def insert_tag(tagName, keyWord, elem):
    if keyWord in elem.text:
        li = elem.text.split(keyWord)

        w = ET.Element(tagName)
        w.text = keyWord
        w.tail = li[1]

        elem.text = li[0]
        elem.append(w)
        return elem
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Sorry, keyWord {keyWord} not found!")
    
tree = insert_tag('w', 'some', p)
ET.dump(tree)

Output:
<p>Here is <w>some</w> text.</p>

